# I don't how to take a group a numbers and divide them all among the total added, such as a GPA calculator

Tags: javascript, function, var

I don't know how to take a value and divide it and return that value

```
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("class1").value);
            var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("class2").value);
            var c = parseInt(document.getElementById("class3").value);
            var d = parseInt(document.getElementById("class4").value);
            var e = parseInt(document.getElementById("class5").value);
            var f = parseInt(document.getElementById("class6").value);
            var g = parseInt(document.getElementById("class7").value);
            var h = parseInt(document.getElementById("class8").value);
            var i = parseInt(document.getElementById("class9").value);

            var x = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
        }
```

Take the value of x and by 9

Comment: Do you just want to sum up the a through i variables and divide the total by 9?

Comment: As in `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x / 9;`?

Comment: Also return from what? Is this the body of a function? Do you actually mean "return" or do you mean putting it in the element with id `result`? if you actually mean "return" then just `return x / 9`.

Comment: Never mind everybody, I figured it out! Thanks anyways for trying to help!! Much appreciated.